# Angular application restarting when clicking button in Microsoft Edge

Tags: angular, forms

I have been working on an Angular application for a while now and have been using Chrome during development.  Last week while doing some testing with Microsoft Edge I found that the application was reloading when a button inside a form was being pressed.  This was not the behavior in Chrome.  The immediate solution was to add type=”button” attribute to the button to prevent the form from submitting.

While doing some more testing I confirmed that a simple button inside a form (no Angular) will cause the form to submit when the button is pressed in both Chrome and Edge.  If I do the same thing in a fresh Angular CLI project I see the same behavior.  Once I add the FormsModule the behavior changes and pressing the button does not submit on either Chrome or Edge.  When I say "submit" I am referring to an HTTP GET for the page.

I have not been able to build a short reproduction of a case where it the button submits in Edge but not Chrome.

My question is, can anyone explain some of the items at play here?

Comment: Buttons inside forms are implicitly set to `type="submit"` most of the time. Make sure to set all your buttons explicitly to `type="button"`, except the real submit button. Also make sure your form subscribes to the `(ngSubmit)` event handler and not `(submit)`.

Answer (score 2):

Buttons are classified as form-associated content. They are part of the HTML specification of elements that have behavior inside a `<form>` tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Form-associated_content

It's stated in the documentation for buttons that you must set the `type` attribute to `button` to disable submitting.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Notes

> Once I add the FormsModule the behavior changes and pressing the button does not submit on either Chrome or Edge.

It is submitting, but all `<form>` tags are captured by the `FormDirective` which overrides the default submit behavior to trigger `(ngSubmit)` events on the form element.

The selectors for the directive are:

```
form:not([ngNoForm]):not([formGroup])
ngForm
ng-form
[ngForm]
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

The documentation states in the form description

> As soon as you import the FormsModule, this directive becomes active by default on all  tags. You don't need to add a special selector.

This directive takes over events for submitting

> If necessary, listen to the directive's ngSubmit event to be notified when the user has triggered a form submission. The ngSubmit event emits the original form submission event.